# cython: private variables in prange

Tags: openmp, cython

I am trying to re-write in cython a fortran subroutine that uses openmp. I have found no difficulty in re-writing the fortran subroutine itself in cython. The non openmp version works fine. However, I am not sure what to do about the openmp directive....

```
!$omp parallel do private(x, y, z)
```

In cython, I understand that you get the openmp parallel do using cython.parallel.prange. However, I don't see how to declare private variables for the loop.

Is this even possible?

thanks for any insight you can provide.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in openmp, but it sounds like what you are looking for is the parallel directive described at http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. [The docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html) say that:

> If you assign to a variable in a prange block, it becomes lastprivate, meaning that the variable will contain the value from the last iteration.  .....  Variables assigned to in a parallel with block will be private and unusable after the block, as there is no concept of a sequentially last value.